# Unable to locate element while select element second time from dropdown

Tags: java, selenium

***strong text***Unable to locate element while select element second time from drop-down.

I have tried wait

```
 String elementSelector = "//*[@id='approverPicker"
                    + iApproversCount
                    + "-list']//div[contains(concat(' ','x-combo-list-item', ' '), 'x-combo-list-item') and contains(text(),'"
                    + name + "')]";

driver.findElement(By.xpath(elementSelector)).click();
```

First Time element is selected but when i try to select second time after adding first one it throws unable to locate element

here is html code:

```
<div class="x-combo-list-inner" id="approverPicker1-list" style="" xpath="1">   <div class="x-combo-list-item" style="" ext:qtip="test@gmail.com">app,auto</div>    <div class="x-combo-list-item" style="text-align:left;" 
 ext:qtip="test@gmail.com">autoi, compl</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item" style="text-align:left;" ext:qtip="test@gmail.com">autoEmployee2, autoEmployee2</div>    
<div class="x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected" style="text-align:left;" ext:qtip="test@gmail.com">autoEmployee, autoEmployee</div> <div class="x-combo-list-item" style="text-align:left;" ext:qtip="test@.com">autoEmployeeui, autoEmployeeui</div>   <div class="x-combo-list-item" style="text-align:left;" ext:qtip="test@gmail.com">bob, sponge</div> <div class="x-combo-list-item" style="text-align:left;"
```

Comment: Do you have the snapshot of the html ?

Comment: Hard to tell without html source code. Try use Select select = new Select(WebElement); select.selectBy...

Comment: It can find drop-down in debug mode but not in run

Comment: I am not able to add screenshot here

Comment: copy paste the HTML code please :)

Comment: <div class="x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected" style="text-align:left;" ext:qtip="">co, co</div>

Comment: @sapana: Please update your question with the HTML code.

Comment: Anyone help me please I have edited My post with HtML code

Comment: @GregBurghardt I have updated Question with HTML code